# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

My AWS Glue job is reading table from data catalog and I am trying to partition it by the last_modified_date column and store it as a parquet file on S3. However getting **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jdf'** error on running the Glue job.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='***', table_name= d['source_table'])

df=datasource0.toDF().withColumn('logged_at_utc',current_timestamp())  

daf=df.write.partitionBy("last_modified_date").mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://***")
datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(daf, glueContext, "datasource0")
```

I'm new to this, is there any other way I can partition my table and write to S3? Thanks.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Could you also paste the entire error log here?

Comment: @RobertKossendey it occurs when i add this line  **daf=df.write.partitionBy("last_modified_date").mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://***")**

Comment: @vivekveeramani unfortunately there is no other error in the log other than this. And I can't seem to find any solutions over the internet either

Comment: [DataFrameWriter.parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet.html?highlight=parquet) does not return a value, hence `daf` is always `None`.

Comment: @averma, is this the entire code? Wondering where _jdf is coming from.

Comment: @werner thanks a lot, mate. That worked!